# How to run store inside foreach loop of Pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to store data according its group for e.g.

```
{("group1"),(1,b,c),(2,f,e),(1,4,3)}
{("group2"),(2,d,e)}
{("group3"),(3,r,e),(4,s,e)}
```

so i want to store (1,b,c),(2,f,e),(1,4,3) in file "group1", (2,d,e) in file "group2" and so on. How can i do this?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Also the class which is generating this data is created by myself so if any changes which can give me the expected output will also help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to look into "org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage"

Comment: While looking at MultiStorage class i got several errors if i copied the same code of MultiStorage in my new class for : val$ctx, super(keyValueSeparator), and for RecordWriter(ctx). can you please explain how can i implement my own MultiStorage class.

Comment: Now got the hint at link for writing MultiStorage class: http://grokbase.com/t/pig/user/11b2qmbnq1/question-on-custom-store-function . The previous problem may be occurring due to jd-gui utility.